# Moving the non-cursor end of the text highlight

Tags: cursor, text

I know of the shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>left arrow</kbd>/<kbd>right arrow</kbd> to extend/retract the text selection, but it moves only at the cursor. Is there a way to move the "tail" of the highlight in the same way?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, there is generally no method to move the other end of the selection character by character at the level of the desktop environment. Specific editors perhaps may implement such feature, but not the ones I know.